# When I am trying to import it to my phpmy admin am getting error #1067 - Invalid default value

Tags: mysql

Error

SQL query:

--

### -- Database: `gym`

### -- --------------------------------------------------------

-- Table structure for table `admin_tbl`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_tbl` (
`adminid` int( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`username` varchar( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` varchar( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON 
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT =3 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'timestamp'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `ON` which you likely copied from:

```
dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When you remove the `ON`, it works fine.

So your result should be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_tbl` (
`adminid` int( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`username` varchar( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` varchar( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT =3 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7fcbf)

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)